# Given $f(x)=(x-3)^2$, $g(x)= \frac 1x$, and $h(x)=f(g(x))$, determine $h'(x)$.

Tags: calculus, functions

> Given $f(x)=(x-3)^2$, $g(x)= \dfrac 1x$, and $h(x)=f(g(x))$, determine $h'(x)$.

Comment: Do you know what the chain rule is? Also, please tell us what you tried and where you got stuck. Otherwise, this question will attract a lot of downvotes.

Comment: Yes I know what a chain rule is but I am not sure where I should start to solve this question and how I should proceed.

Comment: This problem is a direct application of the chain rule. You're trying to take a derivative of the composition of functions $f(g(x))$. The chain rule is what does this. Write down what the chain rule says about the derivative of $f(g(x))$ and then plug in the information given to you in the problem about $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

Comment: I got the answer it's h'(x)= 6/x^2 - 2/x^3. Thank you, I followed the chain rule.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is $$f'(g(x))*g'(x)$$
Chain rule says $$\frac{d}{dx}(f(g(x)))=f'(g(x))g'(x)$$
taking the derivative of f and g, we have
$$-\frac{2}{x^2}(\frac{1}{x}-3)$$
This answer might be wrong, but the steps to solve it are right, you should check it yourself first.

Comment: I got the answer it's h'(x)= 6/x^2 - 2/x^3. Thank you